Пайтон берет "\" не как строку, что делать?
src_file = absolute_path
dst_file = 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\' #StartUp\ в конце StartUp "\"

copy2(src_file, dst_file) 


Всето одного слэша напишите два.

Язык программирования имеет смысл учить до начала его использования. Это я к тому что уже десятый, если не сотый, вопрос на тему "я не знаю что такое строковый литерал".

@mrgervant с r-строками все равно останется проблема из-за последнего слеша - он все равно будет экранировать закрывающую кавычку.

Можно использовать и так: r'd:\document\reports'. Почитайте об использовании r в таком контексте.

@u111 экранизируют романы, а кавычки экранируют.

Кавычки надо экранировать обратными слешами, а обратные слеши - другим обратным слешем.
